undetected_chromedriver to exe, without Chrome
I use undetected_chromedriver in a project, I build the project in exe using pyinstaller, can I somehow prevent the case that the user does not have Chrome installed, add something to dist, now I have added chromedriver.exe and undetected_chromedriver.exe to dist folder and get the error:
INFO:main:\u041e\u0428\u0418\u0411\u041a\u0410: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:50345
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00ACC113+48259]
  (No symbol) [0x00A5CA41]
  (No symbol) [0x009508A3]
  (No symbol) [0x0093F924]
  (No symbol) [0x00981E2C]
  (No symbol) [0x00979320]
  (No symbol) [0x00979167]
  (No symbol) [0x009BA8BA]
  (No symbol) [0x009BA0EA]
  (No symbol) [0x009B0B36]
  (No symbol) [0x0098570D]
  (No symbol) [0x009862CD]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00D86533+2908323]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC3B4B+3159739]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00B6505B+674763]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00B6B21C+699788]
  (No symbol) [0x00A66244]
  (No symbol) [0x00A62298]
  (No symbol) [0x00A6242C]
  (No symbol) [0x00A54BB0]
  BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76287BA9+25]
  RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7709BD2B+107]
  RtlClearBits [0x7709BCAF+191]


self.driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True, options=options,    browser_executable_path="./chromedriver.exe",
                                driver_executable_path='./undetected_chromedriver.exe')



You can extract a portable version of the browser at run-time and then set browser executable path accordingly.  (or let Selenium's built-in webdrivermanager download/install browser/driver pair first...)
